# Accessors are only available when targeting ECMAScript 5 and higher

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-5, accessor

I am trying to run this code, but it is giving me the following errors:

> Animal.ts(10,13): error TS1056: Accessors are only available when
> targeting ECMAScript 5 and higher. Animal.ts(14,13): error TS1056:
> Accessors are only available when targeting ECMAScript 5 and higher.

```
interface IAnimal{
    name : string;
    sayName():string;
}

class AnimalImpm implements IAnimal{
    private _name : string = '[Animal]';
    get name():string{
        return this._name;
    }

    set name(name:string){
        this._name = name;
    }

    constructor(name:string){
        this.name = name;
    }

    sayName():string {
        console.log(`My name is ${this.name}`);
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer is spread across a couple of different responses here.  @jagdish you should answer it yourself!

Answer (score 118):

The only thing which worked for me was to specify the `Target` on macOS and Windows. Please note the parameter `-t` is standing for Target.

```
tsc -t es5 script.ts
```

You can run the command on your terminal.

Answer (score 87):

Try setting up a [tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) file in your project:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5"
  }
  "files": []
}
```

That will tell the TypeScript compiler to target a version specifically.

Comment: I cam across the same error, when running the recommended added flag targeting es5 that works for me:

tsc script.ts --t es5

However, I would like just to have this configured in my tsconfig.json file. I have pasted my tsconfig.json below. Replacing es2017 by es5 in the target value does not resolve the error for me. By the way targeting es2017 which is higher than es5 anyway and should work as well if I am not mistaken. What am I doing wrong?
  
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2017",

Comment: It's hard to tell with just seeing the config in a comment. The comment itself is not complete, for example, because there's a trailing comma and no closing }.  Start with a very basic test and config and then build the config up with the example. Once that works drop it in your project maybe?

Answer (score 35):

I was having the same problem. What I read from the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) is that the tsconfig.json file is ignored if you specify the files.

[image]

My tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": [
    "*.ts"
  ]
}
```

And I run it from command line

```
tsc && node *.js
```

Comment: Wow schizo.  I mean I'm old and sort of hate that node/ts/etc. don't really have a standard dialect (ts-node notwithstanding) but then tsc turns around and silently adopts a useless confusing mode when you try to run it over a single file, cute

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46722359/edit) (it covers answers and any kind of text as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11):

If you're dealing with a *single* file you could do this:

`tsc your-file.ts --target ES2016 --watch`

If you want it inside your **tsconfig.json** for the entire project configuration:

`{ "compilerOptions": { "target": "ES2016" } "files": [] }`

You may want to use either ECMAScript numeric *"es6", "es7", "es8"* or the year of release, like *"ES2015", "ES2016", "ES2017"*.

**ESNext** targets the latest supported ES proposed features.

Comment: this works for me. set target to "es6", warnings are all gone.

Comment: I tried different supported targets here, and they removed the warnings on the accessors. BUT then any JSX code was not recognized. Only setting "target": "es5" worked for both.

Answer (score 8):

In Windows, the

```
tsc --target es5 filename.ts
```

options can be: 'es3', 'es5', 'es6', 'es2015', 'es2016', 'es2017', or 'esnext' (without '' (single quotes)).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for your help. You might want to make your answer even better by adding some explanation.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I only needed to add the target.

```
tsc *.ts --target ES5 && node *.js
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that the solution below could be a very helpful command for all developers here.

You can easily solve it using this command in your [Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_(macOS)), command prompt, [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway), etc.:

`tsc --target ES2016 Animal.ts --watch`

or

`tsc --target es5 Animal.ts --watch`

`--watch` is optional and means that you don't need to compile your code in each modification.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and got it to work with this... for a single file!

`tsc -target "es5" filename && node filename`

- `"es5"` with quotes
- need not mention file extensions
- `tsc -target "es5" filename` - transpiles the typescript to "es5" JavaScript
- `node filename` - runs the [transpiled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler) JavaScript file

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem trying to compile TypeScript code with Visual Studio Code.
This solved the issue:

1) **tsconfig.json** - add the `target` in the `compilerOptions`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",  // <-- here!
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true
    }
}
```

2) **tasks.json** - add the `target` argument:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "build",
            "type": "process",
            "command": "tsc",
            "args": [
                "ts/Program.ts",
                "--outDir", "js",
                "--sourceMap",
                "--watch",
                "--target", "es5"  // <-- here!
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always"
            },
            "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution:

```
tsc file.ts --target ES5 && node file.js
```

**Note:** Ensure you make use of your file name. This would only be applicable for you if the name of your .ts file is **file**.

#### I think a cleaner way of writing that code would have been this

```
class AnimalImpm {
        constructor(private _name?:string){
            this.name = name;
        }

        get name():string{
            return this._name;
        }
    
        set name(name:string){
            this._name = name;
        }
    
        sayName():string {
            console.log(`My name is ${this.name}`);
            return "Hello";
        }
    }

let data = new AnimalImpm('Animal');
    data.name;
    data.name = 'newAnimal';
    data.sayName();
```

Answer (score 1):

I targetted `esnext` and even with this I got the error.
But for me it helped, targeting the .vue files in `tsconfig.json`.
Like:

```json
  "include": [
    "*.ts",
    "*.vue" // << added
  ],
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply set the "es5" in your *tsconfig.json* file:

```
target: "es5"
```

And that all.

Answer (score 0):

If using Visual Studio 2017:

1. Solution Explorer → right-click on the project
2. *Add* → *New Item*
3. (Search section → type this → typescript)
4. Select "TypeScript Json Configuration File"

That’s it. At the end of these steps, *[tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)* will be added to the project with the default set applied to ES5.

You don't have to change anything. Just recompile your project and the error is going to be out.

Comment: typescript doesn't give any result in the search box. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to pass the switch to the TypeScript compiler, so it targets the ECMAScript file. To do that, enter the below code in the terminal:

> tsc (your TypeScript file).ts --target ES5

And run your build JavaScript file:

> node (your JavaScript file)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `tsc myTS.ts --target ES5`.

This is because TypeScript should target the ECMAScript 5 compiler.

Answer (score 0):

It finally worked out for me. Run the file, and then state the target flag:

`tsc script.ts --t es5`

*[Build target not working from tsconfig.json #12645](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12645)*

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any need to specify the extension:

```
tsc -target "es5" filename && node filename
```

Answer (score 0):

I kept having the same issue even after adding this to my tsconfig.json file:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "noEmitOnError": true
  }
}
```

but that was because I was still running `tsc myFileName.ts` in the command line. Instead I just needed to run `tsc` and not include the file name. `tsc` compiles all the `.ts` files :).

Answer (score 0):

Just run this command

```
tsc -target es6 Animal.ts
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the **tsconfig.json** file by the below command.

```
tsc --init
```

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
tsc .\main.components.ts --target ES5
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).