# Accessor is only available when targeting ECMAScript 5 and higher - error message when using TypeScript

Tags: typescript

When I try to compile the below TypeScript using "tsc file.ts," I get the following error (twice):

error TS1056: Accessors are only available when targeting ECMAScript 5 and higher.

According to this article on StackOverflow - [Accessors are only available when targeting ECMAScript 5 and higher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41010780/accessors-are-only-available-when-targeting-ecmascript-5-and-higher) -- I should be able to specify a "tsconfig.json" file, which I've done:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5"
  }
}
```

---

```
export class CPoint {
  constructor(private _x?: number, private _y?: number) {
  };

  public draw() { 
    console.log(`x: ${this._x} y: ${this._y}`);
  }

  public get x() {
    return this._x;
  }

  public set x(value: number) {
    if (value < 0) {
      throw new Error('The value cannot be less than 0.');
    }

    this._x = value;
  }
}
```

I can compile using --target "ES5" but why doesn't tsc read my .json file?
I don't want to have to specify ES5 on every compile.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue is that `tsconfig.json` isn't considered when you manually specify your source files on the command line.

If you run `tsc` with no arguments then the `tsconfig.json` will be picked up automatically.

For more information check this [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6591)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
tsc -t es5 script.ts
```

The compiler sets the target to ES5 when your editor compiles it.